# Clone a shared repo

Tags: git, github

What's the right url to use to clone someone else's repo?

- I can do: `git clone https://github.com/other-user/repo.git` but that
  makes me enter my username/password when I push.
- I tried: `git clone git@github.com:my-username/other-user/repo.git`
  but it didn't work

Comment: Can you add your ssh keys and use ssh-agent on your machine?

Comment: Yes, my ssh is set up correctly and everything works fine when I clone my own repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the right clone url

> I tried: git clone git@github.com:my-username/other-user/repo.git

A repository url doesn't change based on who you are - it is always the same. When cloning via ssh the bit after `:` indicates the repository - i.e. the path to the repository on the remote system.

If in doubt go to https://github.com/other-user/repo, and copy the url from the `SSH clone URL` box. Getting the url from github will also confirm/ensure that you have access to the repository. The right clone url will be of the form:

```
git clone git@github.com:other-user/repo.git
```

I.e. `my-username` will not be in it.

Note that you *don't* need to clone again if you have an existing checkout  - you can simply change the remote's url in the `.git/config` file.

Comment: This works, thanks. I thought my username needed to be in there but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are a collaborator, you can use any of this two alternatives:

```
git clone https://YOUR_USERNAME@github.com/torvalds/linux.git
git clone git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git
```

In the first case, you could leave `YOUR_USERNAME` out, but then you'll be prompted on almost every `fetch`/`pull`/`push` for your username AND password. You can avoid being asked about this at all by creating [a rule like this in your `.netrc` file](https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/1072829), but the safer is to [use the credential helper](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching) to cache it so you have to enter your credentials once in a while.

With SSH URL, you just get authenticated by your keys.

---

If you're not a collaborator of the repository (i.e., you don't have push access to the repo), you can use any of the 3 alternatives offered by the GitHub UI:

```
git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
git clone git@github.com:torvalds/linux.git
git clone http://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

(The last one is sort of deprecated, I think).

You can read about differences and benefits of each at [this GitHub's help article](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use).

Comment: I am a collaborator. None of these are what I'm looking for.